# a way to run a function on CTRL-O / CTRL-I?

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I wrote a little function to highlight a current line when navigating which basically mimics this emacs [package](https://github.com/rolandwalker/nav-flash). It works fine for navigating between windows.

[image: navigation flash]

```
function Util.flash_cursorline()
  vim.cmd([[hi CursorLine guifg=#000000 guibg=#ffffff]])
  vim.fn.timer_start(200, function()
    vim.cmd([[hi CursorLine guifg=NONE guibg=NONE]])
  end)
end
```

```
vim.cmd([[au WinEnter * lua require('util').flash_cursorline()]])
```

Is there an autocommand, or any other way to run a function when jumping between jumplist entries with `CTRL-O`, `CTRL-I` in normal mode?

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. `:h 'cursorline'` isn't sufficient? (I can't tell what you have now because the gif isn't animated AFAICT.)

Comment: In Vim  I you can just do `nnoremap <C-o> <C-o>:call YourFunction<CR>`. This would make the jump, then call the function. Not sure if that would work with Neovim/lua...

Comment: @BLayer I'm using cursorline and it is helpful, but this feature would be nice to have too.

Comment: @mattb thank you, this gives me an idea for the solution

Comment: Cool. Just wanted to make sure you were aware of it (cursorline).

Comment: In my case, as I have `vim.opt.cursorline = false`, I had to add two more lines to get the same function working here, and I have almost given up until figured out what was in plain sight "*CursorLine*".

Comment: By the way, how to add a "repeat" at `timer_start`, so it flashes twice or more?

Answer (score 1):

@mattb's reply gave me an idea to map additional function to `<C-o>` and `<C-i>` and it seems to be working alright.

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<C-o>", "<C-o>:lua require('util').flash_cursorline()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<C-i>", "<C-i>:lua require('util').flash_cursorline()<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })
```

Comment: Nice! But note that the `<space><bar><space>` you included is happening in Normal mode, so those are being interpreted as Normal-mode commands. You'll probably want to skip those. You should also include `{ silent = true }` in your options, to prevent the `:lua` call from flashing on the command line. If this was regular Vimscript, I'd write it as `:nnoremap <silent> <C-o> <C-o>:Lua require('util').flash_cursorline()<CR>`, so you might want to use the equivalent.

Comment: @filbranden good points! I'll modify the answer.

Comment: I edited your answer to also drop the `<bar>`, which in this case was working as https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#bar, which typically moves to a specific column in a line, given by a count. (Without a count, it goes to the first column, which is probably harmless here... But it's still unnecessary and unrelated to the issue itself, so I thought it was better to drop it.)